# How do I set up a network installation?

Tags: installation, networking, pxe

I want to know if the official 700MB installation images can be used to do a network installation. What would  be the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do a network install would be to boot [netboot.me](http://www.netboot.me/) or [billix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/billix/), both of which have Ubuntu network installers provided.  However, both of those options download the image on the fly.

If you are looking to install from a local image over your network connection, follow these instructions for a local netinstall via using DHCP, TFTP, and PXE: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet

Comment: I want to use ubuntu images I have already downloaded

Comment: In that case, feel free to follow these instructions for a local netinstall via using DHCP, TFTP, and PXE:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet

Comment: @Jorge Castro Sounds good.  Answer updated.