# Installing ubuntu on benq joybook a52e (7 yo laptop)

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, system-installation, laptop

so here is my problem. I am trying to install ubuntu from usb (CD drive is dead) on benq joybook a52e laptop. But the problem is that usb drive larger than 256mb can not be recognized as bootable device, or I just don't know how to set it up. Here is a list of boot options in bios:
hdd
usb key
usb fdd
network

So when i plug 256 mb Transcend 120MB JetFlash 110 USB 2.0 Thumb Drive it is seen in bios, but I can't make bootable 14.01 installation version on that. And the usb's i have are 4gb and 16gb that are not recognized in bios (i have no idea why, maybe because it is old laptop?).

I have tried to make a smaller partition in partitioning software, and it did not work. I have also tried different partition formats (fat, fat32) also didn't work.

So can someone help me how to install it properly, and yes I would like 12.xx or later version of Ubuntu on that machine.

Comment: For anyone reading these I was able to install Ubuntu on the laptop using small 120mb drive by making it PXE install. It is the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cd drive would not have helped you either: you need a dvd drive for 14.04.

From your list:

- "network" PXE install might be an option. See [How do I set up a network installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23960/how-do-i-set-up-a-network-installation)
- "hdd" create a 700 Mb-ish partition and put the Ubuntu ISO in there and have the system boot from that partition. See [Install Ubuntu from ISO image directly from hard disk of a system running Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux)

Comment: Hm I will check network pxe install, because the system on laptop is windows xp.

Comment: I can't grasp many of the concepts put in that kinds of installs. Is there a way of installing Ubuntu from windows, but replacing the whole thing so after installation of Ubuntu i am left only with Ubuntu on hdd?

Comment: No. You can not remove the current OS from within the current OS (on any OS for that matter). I believe you will have to rely on either a PXE or an on hdd partition installation (if you system lets you boot from it).

Comment: So i can't remove windows if ubuntu installation is done from windows? Is there a trick to trick bios to recognize my 4gb usb?

Comment: If it curently does not support it: check the upgrade notes for your BIOS to see if a newer version does.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate solution that I currently used in 2020 for a Joybook A52 device or any old device with similar configurations, is **using another newer laptop that are able to boot from USB stick larger than 1 GB**.

### The case:

A friend of mine asked me to install new operating system on his old **BenQ Joybook A52** laptop that already runs Windows XP. I downloaded *`32 bit`* Peppermint OS iso and fired it on an 4 GB USB stick and of course, the laptop does not recognize it during boot, in spite of it was fired on its Windows XP.

I, physically, checked out the laptop's hard disk and I have found it, externally, looks like my own **Toshiba Satellite L850** (*64 bit device*) laptop's hard disk. i.e the dimensions and the SATA interface. Hence, I decided to perform the installation on my own laptop, by removing my laptop's hard disk and replace it with the Joybook's hard disk. The installation worked as a breeze and after complete the installation, I had shutdown my Satellite laptop, removing the hard disk, installing it into the Joybook again and power it on.

Now the Joybook runs its new OS very fine with no any issue.