# How to install ubuntu from windows hdd (not dual boot) without cd, usb or network?

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive

Since somehow i can't manage to install ubuntu from cd (it is broken) can't install from usb (wont boot from usb drive larger than 256mb nor will UNETBOOTIN work from that usb), and i don't have the skills to install from pxe (network install). So is there a way to install (clean install NOT A DUAL BOOT) ubuntu from windows hard drive?

p.s. i might be there is some option in unebootin to "install on hard drive" but I am not sure will that remove windows from my hdd?

Comment: This question is not reproducible since the author hasn't visited the site in more than 5 years.

Answer (score 1):

Short and quick answer (actually you answered it!): Use a netinstall image which is smaller than 256Mb. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Comment: How to make minimal cd on usb on windows? And what after installing minimal? How i get full Ubuntu install?

Comment: You make the usb stick just like the normal one, after install you will get a command line, where you can issue: 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop'. That's all.

Comment: Will minimal cd support network drivers for that old laptop?

Comment: (Quite silly question, sorry... :D) Probably yes, you have to give it a try or first of all specify your laptop's parameters and I will check.

Comment: benq joybook a52e

Comment: @VladimirTurcan to get full ubuntu after installing minimal, you type: `tasksel` when the system reboots and then choose the Ubuntu desktop. Make sure you're connected via ethernet cable just in case.

Comment: I am having difficulty creating minimal cd on usb from windows. Is there any automated method of doing so?

Comment: Did it somehow, but i am not sure how to partition since i do not want to remove one of the partitions on disk which was created in windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is (as mentioned by @frantique) a minimal install option, which you can find on [ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Answer (score 0):

### For reference:

Simply you will need the help of another newer computer. Transfer the hard drive of the old one to be the bootable master at the newer one. Boot the installation media, install the distro. and then return the hard drive again to the older and boot it again. Checkout [this story answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1208293/217641).