# Help install ubuntu w/o cd,dvd or usb

Tags: 14.04, windows-7

I am trying to install ubuntu 14.04 64-bit to my Windows 7 32-bit PC. I have the ISO, but I have no CD's, USB Sticks, or DVD. I've tried UNetBootIn and wubi but that didn't work. So what do I do?

Comment: Are you planning on dual-booting or running Ubuntu within a VM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up a network installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23960/how-do-i-set-up-a-network-installation)

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much whittled yourself down to a network boot install then.  Here's a good resource.

[Ubuntu Installation Guide about a TFTP installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/installation-guide/i386/ch04s05.html)

I'll let others expand on this answer if they like.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I can see the link fine. Are you not able to?

Comment: Hm, now the link works. Earlier it gave me an HTTP 404 response. Possibly a fluke of the web server.